# How do SharePoint index column work?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I have been trying to find out what happens in SharePoint when we select a column as index column? I mean what happens in back end(database level)? I tried many articles but they just say that it improves performance but they don't say how. I found [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9406/why-did-creating-this-new-index-improve-performance-so-much-when-existing-index) question and others related to performance but I couldn't get a complete picture.

Comment: Indexing concept in general or Sharepoint specific?  Not that it matter much, imagine phone book... if you try to find all business in a particular post / zip code and there isn't a quick way to do this since everything is sorted alphabetically by business or person last name... you will have to scan each line in each pages and jut down each entry matching zip code.  Imagine if there is an index page that is sorted by zip code and it just point back to every single entry in the book for business in that particular zip code... which is faster?

Comment: point is, having index in itself does not make things faster.  searching on things that are indexed (in this case if you search by zipcode and you set the zipcode column as indexed column), you will get results faster since you don't have to scan the entire data structure and parse thing inside to see if the zipcode matches.  The index will already done this in advance for you and so you scan the index and find related list entry that way (or rather sharepoint will do this for you).

Comment: Thanx for response. I understand the concept but I am looking for the implementation. Like how is it implemented in DB,what is the structure of the index table etc..

Answer (score -1):

SharePoint mark the column index enabled, and then add records with **item identifier** and **index field id and value** to sql table **NameValuePair_[loc]**.